# no issue is shown but does not work - dwr

Tags: javascript, jsp, dwr

Hi all i am using dwr to handle ajax calls in java-servlet,

this is what is my dwr.xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE dwr PUBLIC
"-//GetAhead Limited//DTD Direct Web Remoting 2.0//EN"
"http://getahead.org/dwr/dwr20.dtd">
<dwr>
    <allow>
        <create creator="new" javascript="TempCardServlet">
            <param name="class" value="com.slingmeadia.notifier.servlet.TempCardServlet"/>
        </create>
    </allow>
</dwr>
```

and this what is my servlet file and in that i call the

```
package com.slingmeadia.notifier.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;


public class TempCardServlet extends HttpServlet {
 @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {


        String funtionType="";
        if(request.getParameter("functiontype")!=null){
            funtionType = (String)request.getParameter("functiontype");
        }
        if(funtionType.equals("logout")){
            processLogout(request, response);
        }else{

        }

    }
@Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processLogout(request, response);
    }
    public Map sampleFill(int empid,String functiontype){
      System.out.println("functiontype : "+functiontype);
        Map employeeData = new LinkedHashMap();
        if(functiontype.equals("add")){
            employeeData.put("name", "Antony");
        }else{
            employeeData.put("name", "Antony");
            employeeData.put("cardnumber", "87896857852");
            employeeData.put("issuedate", "17/01/2012");
        }
        return employeeData;
    }


}
```

and this is how i call the method from jsp file :

```
<script src='dwr/engine.js'></script>
        <script src='dwr/util.js'></script>
        <script src='dwr/interface/TempCardServlet.js'></script>

        <script>
            function getValues(id) {
                var empid = id.value;
                var optionValue = document.getElementById("selectedOption").value;
                TempCardServlet.sampleFill(empid,optionValue,{callback:setValues,async:false});
            }
            function setValues(tempcardMap) {
                if(tempcardMap !=null){
                    document.getElementById("empname").value=tempcardMap.name;
                    document.getElementById("tempcardnumber").value=tempcardMap.cardnumber;
                    document.getElementById("dateofissue").value=tempcardMap.issuedate;
                }
            }
</script>
```

and this how i make a call to javascript method :

```
<td width="55%"><input class="inputBoxes" type="text" name="empid" id="empid" onblur="getValues(this)" /></td>
```

it seems all are good arranged and no issues but it is not working and do not give any excetpion also.

i tried to like this also

in url i typed `http://localhost:8080/acct/dwr/index.html`

it gives me the list of Classes known to DWR: and my class file also is there, when i tried to open the class file from browser and gave some sample input but it is not  giving any error also no output.

Please help me to resolve this.

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.check the dwr path

if you are going to have the view files inside WEB-INF than

```
<script src='dwr/engine.js'></script>         
<script src='dwr/util.js'></script>         
<script src='dwr/interface/TempCardServlet.js'></script>
```

Refering this way will work.if not you have to give proper path like the below

```
<script src='../dwr/engine.js'></script> 
<script src='../dwr/util.js'></script> 
<script src='../dwr/interface/TempCardServlet.js'></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the post i will check and let you know