# How to call the servlet?

Tags: java, servlets

i have a logout link in jsp and i call the logout function like this

```
function logout(){
    document.getElementById("functiontype").value="logout";
    document.forms["frmTempcard"].submit();               
}
```

i call this like following :  `<li><a href="#" onclick="logout()">Logout</a></li>`

when i click on the link i see the following url : `http://localhost:8080/acct/notifier[the jsp file is there in this folder only ]/TempCardServlet`

when i remove the folder name in url it is working fine. so how to redirect to desired servlet?

Please help me.

Comment: What do you mean by "remove the folder name in url"?

Comment: Thanks for all your effort folks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at the `action` attribute of form, as per the code you have shared and the problem description, I feel you need to update `action` of your form.

Currently you would have given `action='TempCardServlet'` which means submit the request to `TempCardServlet` residing in the same URL as the current JSP page. This is relative path reference.

When you specify `action='SomePath'` then browser submits request to `http://server/currenturl/SomePath`. If the path to which you need to submit the request is not in current path then you need to either specify relative path or absolute path in following manner:

Relative Path (in your case): `action='../TempCardServlet'` - this method is not recommended as relative path might break your application

Absolute Path with Application context: `action='/acct/TempCardServlet'` - this would refer to servlet on the same server, drawback of this is that you are hard-coding applicaiton context. To overcome this you can use Servlet API to get current application context and append it to your servlet path - you can also use standard tag libraries to get the context path appended.

Comment: could you also help me on this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448493/how-to-solve-ev-is-undefined-in-mozilla-firefox

Comment: and this too : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11447133/no-issue-is-shown-but-does-not-work-dwr

Answer (score 1):

Make the `action` attribute of your form point to the appropriate URL:

```
<form action="<c:url value='/TempCardServlet'/>" ...>
```

If you need to change it dynamically, add this to your JS code (before the submit, of course):

```
document.forms["frmTempcard"].action = "<c:url value='/TempCardServlet'/>";
```

Answer (score 1):

This:
   `<a href="/myWebApp/servlets/logout">Logout</a>`

... calls your own servlet mapped like this:

```
@WebServlet(name="logout", urlPatterns={ "/servlets/logout" })
public class LogoutServlet extends HttpServlet {
    ...
}
```

... in which you do your logging out logic.